# Years old vs. year old in a descriptive sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number

I need to describe that a product is suitable for specific ages. Which of the follwoing should I use?

This product is suitable only for 7+ ***year*** old children

This product is suitable only for 7+ ***years*** old children

Comment: @Laurel  No. I understand the answer in general but still have doubt what should I use in my specific case and need someone to confirm to me.

Comment: "... children aged 7 and over".  It is better to use that structure. If not you should follow the advice of the duplicate  "7+ year old"